# How to use a geojson file to feed coordinates into catalogue search?

Tags: coordinate-systems, sentinelsat, sentinel-5p

I want to find information on a specific air pollutant, like **Aerosol**, in a certain area using a **geojson** file created on **geojson.io**. I know how to search using a **bbox** that outlines the area I’m interested in, as shown in my code. But how can I use a **geojson** file instead of manually entering the box coordinates?
My code is as follows:

```
time_interval = '2022-07-01', '2022-07-20'
aoi_coords_wgs84 = [73.051014,33.674493,73.100109,33.702932]
aoi_bbox = BBox(bbox=aoi_coords_wgs84, crs=CRS.WGS84)


search_iterator = catalog.search(
    DataCollection.SENTINEL5P,
    bbox = aoi_bbox,
    time=time_interval,
    
    fields={"include": ["id", "properties.datetime"], "exclude": []},

)

results = list(search_iterator)
print("Total number of results:", len(results))

results
```

I have tried using the geometry parameter but had no luck there, maybe I'm doing something wrong.